# What is a word to describe someone in another organization which you collaborate with?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, generic-term

So basically, if I were to say something like 'That guy working on behalf of organization x, has said that he would relay information within 3 working days', what would be a word or term for 'that guy working in/for organization x'?

At first I thought the term 'party' would be appropriate, but when looking up it's definition, it's defined only for political parties (and frat boy parties xD). Furthermore, there seems to be many terms to describe those working in the same organization as one's own, the most formal I can think of being colleague, but none that seem to describe those working as part of another organization that one's own organization is collaborating with.

Comment: If it were a regular relationship you'd likely say "My counterpart over in Company XYZ".

Comment: Would they have to have the same role/skills? Or could they have an entirely different skillset which are applied to help achieve the same aim as myself? Also thanks

Comment: Generally, "counterpart", when used in this sense, would be expected to mean someone with complementary skills and duties.  But used in a slightly different sense it means someone with the same skills and duties as you.

Comment: You can also use *representative*. It is broader and will sate your need.

Answer (score 1):

You might call this person your PoC, or [Point of Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_contact):

> A point of contact (POC) or single point of contact (SPOC) is a person
>   or a department serving as the coordinator or focal point of
>   information concerning an activity or program. A POC is used in many
>   cases where information is time-sensitive and accuracy is important.

Answer (score 0):

I would say *liaison* or *counterpart*

(New Oxford American Dictionary)

**liaison** - communication or cooperation that facilitates a close working relationship between people or organizations: *the head porter works in close liaison with the reception office.*

**counterpart** - a person or thing holding a position or performing a function that corresponds to that of another person or thing in another place: *the minister held talks with his French counterpart.*

Comment: It is always appreciated if you provide a definition and its source. And explain, if needed, how it relates to the op's question.